# How to load all the images from one folder into my web page using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load images from one folder dynamically using jquery

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var dir = "img/"; 
var fileextension = ".jpg"; 
var i = "1";
var n;
$(function imageloop(){
 $("<img />").attr('src', dir + i + fileextension ).appendTo("#images");
 for(i=1;i<n;i++){
 imageloop();
 };
       });   
});
```

But only one image is loading.any mistake here?

The following code is working but i want for loop instead of if else

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var dir = "img/"; 
var fileextension = ".jpg"; 
var i = "1";
$(function imageloop(){
 $("<img />").attr('src', dir + i + fileextension ).appendTo("#images").width(150).height(150);
 if (i==6){
 alert('loaded');
 }
 else{
 i++;
 imageloop();
 };
       });   
});
```

Comment: what is value for n variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Initialize n.
```

your current function

```
var dir = "img/"; 
    var fileextension = ".jpg"; 
    var i = 1;
    var n;
        $(function imageloop(){
            $("<img />").attr('src', dir + i + fileextension ).appendTo("#images");
            for(i=1;i<n;i++){
                imageloop();
            };
       });
```

here value of `i` will never change since it is always calling itself.so it will append `1.jpg` till the time stack limit is over.

change your code to.

```js
        var dir = "img/"; 
        var fileextension = ".jpg"; 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i = 1;
        var n = 3; 
    
        for(i=1;i<n;i++){
            imageloop(i);
         };
     });   
    
    function imageloop(i){
        $("<img />").attr('src', dir + i + fileextension ).appendTo("#images");
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "images">  </div>
```

it will add 2 images.you can have the desired value of `n`.

Comment: ' $("<img />").attr('src', dir + i + fileextension ).appendTo("#images");'  In this line its showing error 'dir is  not defined'

Comment: @moksha check now.

Comment: @moksha no it should display 2.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming var n = 3**

change from

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dir = "img/"; 
    var fileextension = ".jpg"; 
    var i = "1";
    var n;
    $(function imageloop(){
      $("<img />").attr('src', dir + i + fileextension ).appendTo("#images");
     for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        imageloop();
     };
    });   
 });
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var dir = "img/"; 
            var fileextension = ".jpg"; 
            var i = "1";
            var n = 3;
            for(i=1;i<n;i++){
                imageloop(i);
             }  
});
function imageloop(i){
              $("<img />").attr('src', dir + i + fileextension ).appendTo("#images");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you haven't initialized `n`. So your loop doesn't work. Initialize it and it will work.

Also no need to initialize i as `"1"` when you are going to re-initialize it's value in the loop.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dir = "img/"; 
    var fileextension = ".jpg"; 
    var n = 10; // 10 is an example value

    var imageloop = function(){
        $("<img />").attr('src', dir + i + fileextension ).appendTo("#images");
    };

    for(var i=1;i<n;i++){
        imageloop();
    };   
});
```